# How to compare string match in a array?

Tags: php, arrays, string

```
$array = ('Home', 'Design', 'Store');
$str = 'home';
if (in_array($str, $array)) {
   die("Match");
} else {
   die("No Match");
}
```

Result is "`No Match`" => How to fix it to result is "`Match`" ?

Comment: `in_array` is case-sensitive, so 'home' != 'Home' http://us1.php.net//manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: Just wanted to make a notice here. Do not forget about type comparison - for example `in_array(0, array('Home', 'Design'))` will return `true` while `in_array(0, array('Home', 'Design'), true)` won't

Answer (score 2):

As stated Mike K `in_array()` is case sensitive, so you can change cases for every array element and the needle to the lower case (for example):

```
function in_array_case_insensitive($needle, $array) {
     return in_array( strtolower($needle), array_map('strtolower', $array) );
}
```

#### [Demo](https://eval.in/163211)

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`preg_grep`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) which—as the manual states:

> Return array entries that match the pattern

Your code reworked to use it:

```
$array = array('Home', 'Design', 'Store');
$str = 'home';
if (preg_grep( "/" . $str . "/i" , $array)) {
   die("Match");
} else {
   die("No Match");
}
```

Or if somehow regex seems like a bit much, you can use [`array_map`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) with [`strtolower`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) to normalize your data for an `in_array` check like this:

```
$array = array('Home', 'Design', 'Store');
$str = 'home';
if (in_array(strtolower($str), array_map('strtolower', $array))) {
   die("Match");
} else {
   die("No Match");
}
```

**ADDITION:** I made a claim in comments that `preg_match` would be faster than `array_map`, [but doing some tests online with my code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/54b18a1ad3bdfc3a38cf49be51c7f8464edeb028) shows that is not the case here at all. So use whichever function you feel better with. Speed seems to favor `array_map`.

- preg_grep: 2.9802322387695E-5 sec
- array_map: 1.3828277587891E-5 sec

Comment: -1 for using regex when built-in functions work fine.